# Spring boot - sending emails with Logback

Tags: java, logging, spring-boot

I am trying to configure Logback to send emails whenever an exception (Logging level: ERROR) occurs. I have not been able to make it work so far so I would like to ask for your help with the configuration.

I have a Spring boot application where some processing is done:

```
private void foo() {
 try {
  // do something
 } catch (Exception e) {
  log.error("Logging my exception");
 }
}
```

I would like to trigger an email whenever this error is logged. I followed some [tutorials](http://maciejwalkowiak.pl/blog/2012/04/03/application-errors-notification-with-logback/) and I added **logback.xml** and **smtp-appender.xml** to my `resources` directory:

**logback.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
    <include resource="smtp-appender.xml" />
    <logger name="com.mycompany" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="SMTP" />
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

**smtp-appender.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<included>
    <appender name="SMTP" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
        <smtpHost>xxx</smtpHost>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>password</password>

        <to>test@email.com</to>
        <from>me@email.com</from>
        <subject>testError</subject>

        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout" />

    </appender>
</included>
```

I have setup local smtpserver on localhost via `sendmail`. I have also tried with AWS smtp server and Gmail. None of these services worked for me so far.

The problem is that I do not receive any email after the exception and there is literally no output corresponding to the logback (besides the `log.error()` output, of course) which makes me think that the application does not even know about these config files...

These are my maven dependencies in **pom.xml**:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20141113</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: i don't see the **javabeans activation framework** included in your pom and it is needed to send mail via the logging

Comment: I added the dependency to pom: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation/1.1.1 but it does not solve the issue

Comment: neither logback and slf4j are included

Comment: They are included in Spring... I am using Slf4j for loggin into console and into log file.

Comment: try to put at debug the mail properties so you should see in the main lo what it is happen between JAVA and you mail provider

Comment: I'd suggest a different thought - are you sure you really want to send out emails everytime an error is logged? What about having a separate service aggregating log files and scanning them, and sending out an e-mail (or any other kind of push notification) when the first error is found, but - for example - not more than 1 every 5 minutes, to avoid flooding your inbox?

Answer (score 3):

Default entry for port in smtpappender is 25, gmail is using authentication for smtp services, and you need use ports 587 for TLS and 465 for SSL.

I would say this might be your problem.

Try to setup mail server on your local machine first without authentication, and try is your appended works. then try to find how to configure it for gmail.

From page  http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#gmailSTARTTLS

## SMTPAppender for Gmail (STARTTLS)

```
<configuration>   
  <appender name="EMAIL" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
    <smtpHost>smtp.gmail.com</smtpHost>
    <smtpPort>587</smtpPort>
    <STARTTLS>true</STARTTLS>
    <username>YOUR_USERNAME@gmail.com</username>
    <password>YOUR_GMAIL_xPASSWORD</password>
    
    <to>EMAIL-DESTINATION</to>
    <to>ANOTHER_EMAIL_DESTINATION</to> <!-- additional destinations are possible -->
    <from>YOUR_USERNAME@gmail.com</from>
    <subject>TESTING: %logger{20} - %m</subject>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
      <pattern>%date %-5level %logger - %message%n</pattern>
    </layout>       
  </appender>

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="EMAIL" />
  </root>  
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have tried sending the email from localhost (I setup the sendmail smtp server locally) but it did not work either. I believe that the problem is not in specifying ports and host configuration but in the whole integration in general...

Comment: @Smajl maybe, with configuration which you had, i would not work anyway. if you think it is some issue with integration, try to debug your application check is anything is being passed to appender, and what magic is happening there.

Comment: This works.. Thanks for the help, well actually for the link. Because it seems that xml structure has slightly changed. So I found my way through the link that you shared. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Pls include following (from my working project) on pom.xml & logback.xml in order to get error mail :-

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

**logback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="errMailer" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
      <smtpHost>xxx</smtpHost>
      <smtpPort>25</smtpPort>
      <from>me@gmail.com</from>
      <to>you@gmail.com</to>
      <subjectStr>App Err Mail</subjectStr>
      <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout"/>
      <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
          <level>ERROR</level>
      </filter>
  </appender>
    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="errMailer" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this does not solve the problem.

Comment: This is a working piece of code from my active project. Pls share details on what issue you got after using this with supporting error stacktrace.

Comment: Not sure what to include... I used your code and the error message was displayed in console but no email was triggered (or it was triggered but I did not receive it). What do you mean by "supporting error stacktrace?" I use level: DEBUG which supports ERRORs

Comment: I think then most likely your network is not allowing the triggerred mail to go out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable Marker based triggering of email.

include an evaluator in your logback.xml under SMTP appender
 refer below link

http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#OnMarkerEvaluator

then add below logic in your Exception catch block,pass Marker object to logger method if you want to send email like below -

```
Marker notifyAdmin = MarkerFactory.getMarker("NOTIFY_ADMIN");
logger.error(notifyAdmin,
  "This is a serious an error requiring the admin's attention",
   new Except
ion("Just testing"));
```

its possible that in some scenario you dont want to send email and only want to log the exception then just dont pass Marker object to logger method.

```
logger.error("This is a serious an error requiring the admin's attention",
   new Except
ion("Just testing"));
```